# Client Returns Network Error, but Successful Server POST Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, kubernetes, amazon-eks, http-status-code-504

[**RESPONSE HEADER**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uUKq.png)

Why am I receiving a network error? Does anyone have a clue what layer this is occurring / how I can resolve this issue?

**What I've Tried**
(1) Checked CORS... everything seems to be ok.
(2) Tried to add timeouts in YAML file as annotations in my LB.
(Note) The request seems to be timing out after 60 seconds

**Process:**
(1) Axios POST request triggered from front via button click.
(2) Flask server (back) receives POST request and begins to process.
[ERROR OCCURS HERE] (3) Flask server is still processing request on the back; however the client receives a 504 timeout, and there is also some CORS origin mention (don't think this is the issue though, as I've set my CORS settings properly, and this doesn't pop up for any other requests...).
(4) Server responds with a 200 and successfully sets data.

**Current stack:**
(1) AWS EKS / Kubernetes for deployment (relevant config shown).
(2) Flask backend.
(3) React frontend.

My initial thoughts are that this has to do with the deployment... works perfectly fine in a local context, but I think that there is some timeout setting; however, I'm unsure where this is / how I can increase the timeout. For additional context, this doesn't seem to happen with short-lived requests... just this one particular that takes more time.

Answer (score 1):

If it's failing specifically for long running calls then you may have to adjust your ELB idle timeout. It's 60 seconds by default. Check out the following resource for reference:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/

Some troubleshooting tips [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http504).

Comment: Hey Faheem, I've already tried this unfortunately...

Comment: service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "300" under annotations